# Is .meta. regionserver would be a bottleneck in Hbase?

Tags: hbase

We know there is only one RegionServer to handle .META. data in Hbase, all of the write/read requests would go through the .META. Regionserver first, so would this point become the bottle neck. 
Actually, at this point I more like Cassandra, because Cassandra could have multiple coordinators which acts the same role as .META. RS in Hbase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read and writes don't go through meta.
read and writes goes directly to the region server hosting the specific key requested.

meta is scanned "once" by the client to get the mapping (start-key:end-key, region server). After the client has the mapping of the location it talks directly to the region servers hosting the data.

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/04/how-scaling-really-works-in-apache-hbase/